# Virtual Box Installation Error: "Invalid Drive: G: \"

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualbox, windows-installation

I have been trying to install VirtualBox. However, I keep getting the error "Invalid Drive: G:. I do not have a G: drive.

I tried using subst G: C:\ and different versions of virtualbox but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Thanks [image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS3dS.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the very late reply, but I just had the same issue and was able to fix it.

My issue was that I had a drive labeled H: without a G: drive. What I did to fix it was:

1. Open Disk Manager
2. Right click on your drive with the last later. i.e. you have drive C: D: E: and H: click on H:
3. Select change drive letter then "Change..." then change the letter to G:
4. Click OK then you should be good to install VBox!

Comment: I'm quite surprised that this actually works. Quite a strange bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This could be due to a past or failed install, in which case you will need to run `regedit` and delete the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\VirtualBox` key.

Comment: Thank you for hint. :)
Actually just need to delete value inside "InstallDir" string  (i had "R:\Virtual Box\" ).

Answer (score 1):

```
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\VirtualBox /v InstallDir
```

Run this in command line

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).